# Given any commutative ring $R$ with unity, $R[X]$ has infinitely many maximal ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, polynomial-rings

Hope this isn't a duplicate.

I was trying to answer the following questions:

(i) Let $k$ be any field. Then prove that $k[X]$ has infinitely many maximal ideals.

(ii) Using (i) prove that, given any commutative ring $R$ with unity, $R[X]$ has infinitely many maximal ideals.

My attempt:

(i) If $k$ is  infinite, then the collection of ideals of the form $(x-a) \forall a \in k$ will suffice.

For finite fields I argue by contradiction. Begin by assuming that there are only finitely many prime polynomials, a listing of them in $k[X]$ say, $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ . Next we define $p_{n+1} := p_{1} \cdots p_{n} +1$ then $p_{n+1} > p_{j} \forall 1\leq j\leq n $ and none of them divide it i. e. proceed like Euclid's argument for proving infinitely many primes.

(ii) By Krull's theorem, any non-zero commutative ring with unity has a maximal ideal. Let $\mathscr{M}$ be a maximal ideal of $R$. Then $\frac{R}{\mathscr{M}}$ is a field, we consider $\frac{R}{\mathscr{M}} [X]$ , then by part (i), $\frac{R}{\mathscr{M}} [X]$ has infinitely many maximal ideals. Since,$\frac{R}{\mathscr{M}} [X] \cong \frac{R[X]}{\mathscr{M}[X]}$ , thus $\frac{R[X]}{\mathscr{M}[X]}$ must have maximal ideals.

Now any ideal of $\frac{R[X]}{\mathscr{M}[X]}$ is of the form $\frac{I}{\mathscr{M}[X]}$ where $I$ is an ideal of $R[X]$ containing $\mathscr{M}[X]$. So any maximal ideal of $\frac{R[X]}{\mathscr{M}[X]}$ is an ideal of $R[X]$ containing ${\mathscr{M}[X]}$, say $J$. But I don't know whether $J$ is maximal in $R[X]$ or not.

How to cross the hurdle? Also if there are mistakes in my arguments please point them out.

Comment: Also, the algorithm for generating infinitely many primes might not give you primes. E.g. $p_{n+1}$ might not be prime, just like $2, 7$ are primes, but $(2)7+1 = 15$ is not.

Comment: I've edited the expression, please tell me whether it works now.

Comment: No, so the thing is that there is no (easy) algorithm for generating infinitely many primes besides brute force (at least to my knowledge). Remember Euclid's proof: although $p_{n+1}$ might not be prime, what do you know about it?

Comment: @4-ier i hope this is what you were suggesting

Comment: Yeah, that is more or less what I meant. For the sake of showing that you got it down, maybe you might want to explain how to "proceed like Euclid's argument..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the ideal correspondence theorem, a maximal ideal of $R[X]/\mathscr{M}[X]$ gives a maximal ideal of $R[X]$.

Answer (score 2):

About your argument to find infinitely many irreducible polynomials, you cannot be sure $p_1\cdots p_n +1$ is irreducible. But it is divisible by an irreducible polynomial $p_{n+1}$, that cannot be equal to any $p_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.

To construct the maximal ideals in $R[X]$, just consider the kernels of the compositions, which are surjective, $$R[X]\to  \frac{R}{\mathscr{M}} [X] \to     \frac{\frac{R}{\mathscr{M}} [X]}{I}$$ for $I$ moving on the maximal ideals of  $\frac{R}{\mathscr{M}} [X]$. They are clearly maximal (since the quotient is a field) and different.